# Simple water ball simulation?

Tags: fluid-simulation, mantaflow

So its seems simple enough but I cant seem to get the result im looking for. Its just a spinning water ball like the one seen in Harry Potter.

[image]

I thought you could just turn off gravity and quick liquid a sphere thats rotating via keyframes but that doesnt work, the liquid still falls immediately, even with no gravity.

The closest Ive gotten is using quick liquid on a sphere set to geometry and putting a vortex force field in the middle. The fluid spins but quickly gets stretched out to the domain borders.

Can you change the shape of the domain perhaps?

Comment: If it's not meant to be acted on by outside forces, consider using a shader for this.  A simulation would be a lot of calculation but the end result is still a sphere

Comment: In 2.93, at least, you don't turn off gravity, you turn off the Gravity influence setting in the Domain's Field Weights; but if you do that all you'll get is a ball of water that doesn't move.

Answer (score 6):

### Fluid Sim

- for Domain object, under *Physics Properties > Fluid > Field Weights* set **Gravity** to zero (or set Force Field of effector object higher)
- add **Sphere**, search for Quick Liquid
- add **Force Field** (Empty with Physics > Force Field enabled) > type Force > Point into a center of sphere
- add some distractor ... it can be duplicated previous *Empty* just with positive *Strength*
- animate this "distractor" to generate some movement of liquid

... all additional setup depends on desired appearance (if you have some specific needs please add some reference.

[image]

### Edit:

Sorry I didn't notice, you aimed to HP orb waterball ... try

- add Spiral curve (enable *Extra Curve* addon for that)
- animate spinning
- enable Physics > Force Field > Vortex > Curve Guide (here Strength -4)

[image]

---

*When I watched the reference a few times now, it seems to be a fake ... like a mesh sphere with spiral edge, )spinning and emitting just a falling liquid :)*

Comment: that's awesome!!

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Allen Simpson - use a shader something like this for the "water ball" (object is just a simple sphere). Use a Value Node with *#frame* entered in the field to make the value match the frame. Slow it down a bit by dividing it, and connect it to a Vector Rotate node to make the ball "spin" when animated.

[image: Water1]

For the dripping water, make a second (smaller) sphere, and make it the instance object of a Particle System attached to the big water ball. Give "water drops" the same material as the main water ball.

[image: Water2]

Play around with the particle settings a bit (scale and scale random are important), and then animate. End result looks something like this:

[image: SpinOrb]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for the in depth explanation!